# Парсинг строки в дату android ошибка

Tags: android, дата

Есть дата и время:

```
Thu, 14 Mar 2019 14:00:56 GMT
```

Есть код для перевода в дату:

```
String str_date = response.headers().get("Date");
Date localTime = null;
try {
localTime = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.getDefault()).parse(str_date);
System.out.println("TimeStamp is " + localTime.getTime());
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

и как ни странно есть ошибка:

```
System.err: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu, 14 Mar 2019 14:00:56 GMT"
```

хотя все правильно расписано. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в локализации, поставьте `Locale.ENGLISH`

```
new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(str_date);
```